# Android Honeycomb and USB Devices

Tags: android, usb, android-3.0-honeycomb

According to Android Honeycomb it supports USB peripherals. I am interested in connecting a credit card reader with USB and another device. My questions are the following:

Will the Android device support a USB Hub?
How can I program to the credit card device? What would I need to ask for the development of lets say a Magtek Credit Card Reader?

If anyone can help me I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MagTek provides an Android development kit for SCRA card readers on their support site.  It includes guidance, sample code and their custom library.  You should use this as a starting point.  You will need a usb capable Android device to test the sample code.  However, to begin with, you may want to use the Android emulator for running the software until you get your build working.  If you try to use the sample code with the emulator, you will have to remove calls to the library or you will see application errors.  If you need help using the emulator, I have a post on my blog which explains it here: http://www.veriserver.net/cgi/tech/?p=39

The following is what the MagTek demo program will look like on the Android 4.0 emulator if you get that far:

Once you get this far, you will be ready to load the sample program on an Android device and try it with a MagTek card reader.

Answer (score 0):

Android 3.0 + supports Android USB Host and Accessory APIs.
Question is too generic to answer in this post. 
Please refer to the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/index.html)

Comment: Basically, what would be my steps into creating an app that talks to the credit card swiper? How would i go about talking to the device once the i connect the cable to the device? Little bit of guidance help.